# (Swift) スライダーバーで画像を変更するが処理が遅い対応

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

iOSプログラム(Swift)でsliderバーで変更した際に画像をhttpアクセスして取得した画像を表示するプログラムを作っています。同期処理にするとスライド動作が非常に重くなります。非同期にすると必要の無い画像を律儀に取得して画像が出るまで時間がかかります。やりたいことはスライドバー変更時に前にたまっていたキューをキャンセルして、最後のキューのみ処理させたいと思います。非同期の際のソースの一部を載せておきます。どうやればいいかご存知の方はご教授ください。

```
@IBAction func slidertime(sender: UISlider) {
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, { () -> Void in
        var urlstring = "http://test.com/img.php?number=" + String(Int(sender.value * 100))
        var url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
        var err: NSError?
        var imgeData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
        self.thumbnail.image = UIImage(data:imgeData)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

スライダーを動かして、動かし終わった時のみ処理をしたいということですよね？

1. スライダーの最新の値を保持
2. タイマーなどで一定間隔で「現在の値」と「保持した値」を比較
3. 現在の値と保持した値が同一な場合に処理

といった処理ではいかがでしょうか。

Comment: スライドバーが変更されて、一定時間が経ったあとの処理が始まるまでの時間を無くしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

スライダーのvalueChangedイベントではなく、touchUpInsideイベントが走った時に画像を取得するのはどうですか？？